# Round down to full hundred

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi there I want to round down an amount to full hundred:
Examples 
23009 rounded 23000,
23099 rounded 23000,
23199 rounded 23100,

My function do not work, because it rounds mathematically.

```
$("#span_berechnungsgrundlage").text(berechnungsgrundlage);
var berechungsgrundlage_gerundet = Math.round(berechnungsgrundlage / 100) * 100;   
alert(berechungsgrundlage_gerundet);
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 13):

Use `Math.floor`.

`Math.floor` - Round a number downward to its nearest integer:

```
var berechungsgrundlage_gerundet = Math.floor(berechnungsgrundlage / 100) * 100;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Math.floor`:

```
Math.floor(number / 100) * 100;
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/duLG9/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `Math.round` with `Math.floor`.